# Django modelform NameError: name 'check_in' is not defined

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Hi everyone I am a beginner in django, building a lodge reservation system with django3.0 and i can't seem to get my modelform to generate a proper queryset to get data in my Reservations model, i keep getting the NameError error message everytime i try enter a new date through my view and right now im not quite sure how to properly solve this error

here is my **models.py:**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


now = timezone.now
end = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=2)
room_choices = [
        ('single_room', 'Single Room'),
        ('double_room', 'Double Room'),
        ('executive_room', 'Executive Room'),
    ]



class Reservation(models.Model):
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=room_choices, default=room_choices[1])
    check_in = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    check_out = models.DateField(default=end)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Reservation'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reservations'
```

I would like to add validation statements later in views.py for price and number of rooms depending on the room_type the user selected so disregard the field for now

here is my **forms.py:**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Reservation

class AvailabilityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = [
            "room_type",
            "check_in",
            "check_out",

        ]
        widgets = {
            'check_in': forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'),
            'check_out': forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'),
        }
```

If someone knows how to get the widgets to work properly outside of admin, displaying the calender onclick and not not just a charfield with a datefield inside, please also help me fix this problem as well

here is my **views.py:**

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from datetime import timedelta, date
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from . import forms
from .models import Reservation 


def availability(request):
    form = forms.AvailabilityForm()
    reservation = Reservation
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AvailabilityForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid:
            reserve = form.save(commit=False)
            reserve.reservation = reservation

            # check whether the dates are valid
            # case 1: a room is booked before the check_in date, and checks out after the requested check_in date
            case_1 = Reservation.objects.filter(check_in__lte=reserve.check_in).filter(check_out__gte=check_in)

            # case 2: oom is booked before the requested check_out date and check_out date is after requested check_out date
            case_2 = Reservation.objects.filter(check_in__lte=check_out, check_out__gte=check_out).exists()

            #case3: room is booked in a date which lies between the two requested check-in/check-out dates
            case_3 = Reservation.objects.filter(check_in__gte=check_in, check_out__lte=check_out).exists()

            # if either of these is true, abort and render the error
            if case_1 or case_2 or case_3:
                return render(request, "availability.html", {"errors": "This room is not available on your selected dates", "form": form})  
            # else dates are valid
            reserve.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Room is available for your stay here')
            return redirect("/complete_booking")
    return render(request, "availability.html", {"form": form})
```

i have tried different methods to try get my view to validate the check_in and check_out objects as you can see case1 and case2 use different filtering techniques but neither seem to work, any help would be appreciated as to where i'm going wrong and how to fix it

Comment: in case 1, you are not defining `check_in` that's being used in `.filter(check_out__gte=check_in)`.

Comment: @NalinDobhal could you clarify a bit more i'm not sure i understand i tried changing ```.filter(check_out__gte=check_in)``` to ```.filter(check_out__gte=check_out)``` and it still gives me the same NameError

Comment: first I would like you to add the error traceback. add the entire traceback. (no image please)

Comment: @NalinDobhal the traceback is too long to paste it here is there a certain section you were looking for?

Comment: Actually the entire traceback will help. It will show the exact exact error with correct line number.

Comment: @NalinDobhal ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karabo\Envs\technocrats2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Karabo\Envs\technocrats2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Karabo\Envs\technocrats2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 ```

Comment: ``` File "C:\Users\Karabo\Documents\technocrats2\core\views.py", line 160, in availability
    case_1 = Reservation.objects.filter(check_in__lte=check_in).filter(check_out__gte=check_out).exists()
NameError: name 'check_in' is not defined
[17/Jan/2020 21:47:25] "POST /availability/ HTTP/1.1" 500 81808 ```

Comment: not sure if you can read it properly didn't know which tag is used to show traceback markdown

Comment: this is exactly I said earlier, you are not defining **check_in** that is getting used in `check_in__lte=check_in)`. You need to define those variable.

Comment: @NalinDobhal thank you very much i managed to create the variables and get the model to work by: ```check_in = reserve.check_in
check_out = reserve.check_out ```

Comment: I added that my previous comment as an answer, please accept that if that helped :)

Comment: @NalinDobhal i can't vote yet i don't have enough points but i'll come back to it in the future when i do have enough points

Comment: No issue, I just answered to indicate that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, the error is:

```
File "C:\Users\Karabo\Documents\technocrats2\core\views.py", line 160, in availability 
case_1 = Reservation.objects.filter(check_in__lte=check_in).filter(check_out__gte=check_out).exists()
NameError: name 'check_in' is not defined
```

After checking the traceback, it is clear that you haven't define any `check_in` variable. You need to define the variable before using it.

```py
check_in = "18-01-2020" # value you want to use in queryset. 
case_1 = Reservation.objects.filter(check_in__lte=reserve.check_in).filter(check_out__gte=check_in)
```